# Simple Editor Templates

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, templates

I'm trying to mask textboxes using jquery ie: phone numbers. I thought a better way to do it might be to apply a class to any field that I give the UIHint of "phone" to on the model.  I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this with basic string fields.  The datetime examples that abound are great, but they are based on a specific type.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this? Or slap me upside the head if it's a bad idea?  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC 3, you can use a data annotation on your model, like so:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^([\(]{1}[0-9]{3}[\)]{1}[\.| |\-]{0,1}|^[0-9]{3}[\.|\-| ]?)?[0-9]{3}(\.|\-| )?[0-9]{4}$")]
public string PhoneNumber{get; set;}
```